# Prepend to array, but keep the indexes with PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array that are already sorted.

Now I would like to take all the arrays that have a sub array value 0 and put them at the start of the array.

This is what I tried to do:

```
        foreach($dealStatsArray as $deal_id => $dealStats)
        {
            if($dealStats['revenueY'] == 0)
            {

                $tmpArray[$deal_id] = $dealStats; // Store the array
                unset($dealStatsArray[$deal_id]); // Unset the current one, since it is not in right position

                array_unshift($dealStatsArray, $tmpArray); // Prepend the tmp array, to have it at the beginning of the array
            }
        }
```

Now problem is that array_unshift() does:

*"All numerical array keys will be modified to start counting from zero"* -php net array_unshift()

Which mess up the rest of the code I got because I need to keep the indexes on $dealStatsArray, and the index for the new prepended array should be the $deal_id and not 0.

How can I do this? And I need a solution that can manage to prepend 2 or 3 times to the beginning of the array, just like it works fine with array_push (appending) I would like to do that, but just prepending

**Update:** Here is my currently uasort function, that are sorting the array after the revenueY value, so that the highest number are in the start of the array and then descending..

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    if (($a["revenueY"]) == ($b["revenueY"])) {
        return 0;
    }
    return (($a["revenueY"]) > ($b["revenueY"])) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($dealStatsArray, "cmp");
```

Now if I follow @thaJeztah's answer, which partly works, then I added this under:

```
function sortbyRevenueY($a, $b) {
    if ($a['revenueY'] == $b['revenueY']) {
       return 0;
    }
    return ($a['revenueY'] == 0) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($dealStatsArray, 'sortbyRevenueY');
```

But this does not work correct, It does take all the revenueY==0 arrays and prepend at the beginning of the array, but then the rest of the arrays gets unsorted (highest to lowest, the first uasort())

Here's my **final goal**: To have an array where all the revenueY==0 are at the beginning of the array, and after these the top revenue are coming after and then descending to lowest revenue at the end of the array.

Comment: Please give one or two examples of the existing array, index for the new element, and expected output.

Comment: how do you imagine that to work? if I have an array looking like this `array(0=>'a',1=>'b')` what would your "prepend" do? overwrite the value at 0? insert something at -1?

Comment: @ITroubs 'associative' arrays in PHP can be sorted while maintaining their key/value relation. I.e. having an array `array(2 => 'c', 1 => 'b', 0 => 'a')` should be possible

Comment: @ITroubs the OP's original code will not work, but using uasort() probably will make it possible, I guess even with numeric keys

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can probably achieve this by 'sorting' the array using a custom callback and `uasort()`;

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php

```
function sortbyRevenueY($a, $b) {
    if ($a['revenueY'] == $b['revenueY']) {
       return 0;
    }

    if (0 == $a['revenueY']) {
       return -1;
    }

    if (0 == $b['revenueY']) {
       return 1;
    }

    return (($a["revenueY"]) > ($b["revenueY"])) ? -1 : 1;
}

uasort($dealStatsArray, 'sortbyRevenueY');

print_r($dealStatsArray);
```

Haven't been able to test it and the 'callback' method may need some tweaking, however, `uasort()` allows you to sort an array using a custom 'callback' method that determines 'how' the array should be sorted. The values inside the array will be sorted, **without** losing the key/value relation.

My example is just to illustrate how you can achieve this, but, as mentioned, may need to be tweaked.

**[update]**
I've updated by example to attempt to combine 'regular' sorting and sorting by '0' into a single callback. Again untested, but maybe this work. Please test this updated example.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. This works ofcourse, but problem is I have, as mentioned, an already sorted array (that has been sorted with uasort too with custom callback), and when I do this second uasort() it do prepend the arrays with revenueY == 0, but then the rest gets unsorted?

Comment: My first sort are sorting the whole array so that the highest revenueY gets at the top and then descending. But besides this I wish all with revenueY that are 0 to be on top. I dont know if it is possible to make one single uasort with one callback function that can handle and sort by this ?

Comment: I've tried to modify my callback method to combine both 'regular' sorting and sorting for on the '0' values. Don't know if it works (maybe -1 and 1 should be reversed in the 'revenueY == 0' parts)

Answer (score -1):

You could try merging the arrays instead of unshifting:

```
$dealStatsArray = array_merge($tmpArray, $dealStatsArray);
```

So no matter how many items `$tmpArray` will have, they will be at the beginning

Comment: that realy messes the keys up! look at the documentation and especially at the example! if the keys are numeric then they will be shifted.